# password_verify() does not match with password in database

Tags: php, mysql, php-password-hash

I am creating a user login page. I used `password($pass,PASSWORD_BCRYPT)` in inserting the data into the database but on trying to verify the password with `password_verify($password,$salt)` the values does not match.

I am sure that the data `$salt` retrieved from the database is correct but it does not match. Can you advise how I can troubleshoot it further? I have searched this thoroughly but cant find any answer.

This is my login code below:

```
<?php 
      // if form submitted 
      // check supplied login credentials 
      // against database
      } 
      else {   $username = $_POST['username'];   
                $password = $_POST['password'];  
      // check input   
      if (empty($username)) {   
      die('ERROR: Please enter your username');   
      }   
      if (empty($password)) {   
      die('ERROR: Please enter your password');  
      }  
      // attempt database connection   
      include("memberconnect.php");
       $pdo = new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$database);  

      if (!$pdo) { 
      die("ERROR: Could not connect: (" . $pdo->errno .")" .$pdo->error); 
      }  
      // escape special characters in input 
      $username = stripslashes($username);  
      // check if usernames exists   
      $sql = "SELECT Login_Name FROM memberdirectory WHERE Login_Name = '$username ' ";  
      if ($result = mysqli_query($pdo,$sql)) {   
      $row = mysqli_num_rows($result);    
      // if yes, fetch the encrypted password  
      if ($row == 1) {     
      $sql = "SELECT Password FROM memberdirectory WHERE Login_Name = '$username' ";  
      // encrypt the password entered into the form   
      // test it against the encrypted password stored in the database   
      // if the two match, the password is correct 
      if ($result = mysqli_query($pdo,$sql)) {  
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  
      $salt = $row[0];   
      if (password_verify($password,$salt)) 
      {    
      // password correct 
      // start a new session  
      // save the username to the session 
      // if required, set a cookie with the username   
      // redirect the browser to the main application page 
      session_start();          
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;  
      if ($_POST['sticky']) {    
      setcookie('name', $_POST['username'], mktime()+86400);   
      }         
      header('Location: main.php');         
      } 
      else
      {           echo 'You entered an incorrect password.'; 
      echo strlen($salt);
      var_dump(password_verify('$password',$salt));
      var_dump($salt);
      }      
      }
      else { 
      die("ERROR: Could not execute $sql (" .$pdo->errno.")".$pdo->error);      
      }     
      } else { 
      echo 'You entered an incorrect username.';    
      }   
      } else { 
      die( "ERROR: Could not execute $sql (" .$pdo->errno.")".$pdo->error); 
      }  
      // close connection  
      unset($pdo); } 
      ?>
```

Comment: First of all you need to fix the indentation in your code. Also, your code fails because `'$var'` does not interpolate the variable. Remove the single quotes around it!

Comment: You have SQL injection vulnerabilities in this code. Don't put it live until you've escaped your user inputs, or switched to parameterised queries.

Comment: I've reworded your request for the troubleshooting to be done by a reader - that's a recipe for downvotes here. I've changed it so that you are asking for help - that's probably more of an accurate reflection of how this site works anyway. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

`password_verify` checks the password against a hash. To get the hash, which by the looks would be saved to the database, you would use `password_hash`. This is even stated in [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) php.net manual pages. Please recheck your hashing.

The only `password` function I am aware of is for MySQL that is used mainly for MySQL authentication. If you are using a custom function `password`, you will have to resend the entered password and salt through or reverse engineer the hash.